# »Ich weiß nicht, ob du es weißt, ABER …«

Tags: phrase, question

Sehr oft stoße ich in gesprochener Sprache über folgendes Konstrukt:

- Ich weiß nicht, ob hier alle mit der Evolutionstheorie vertraut sind, **aber** das ist im Grunde eine Theorie über …
- Ich weiß nicht, ob du es bereits weißt, **aber** ich bin seit einer Woche arbeitslos.

Der Sprecher fragt sich also, ob seine Information neu oder redundant ist, wartet aber nicht auf Antwort, sondern beginnt sofort damit, diese Information zu artikulieren. So weit, so gut, aber warum leitet er das mit einem "aber" ein?

Das erscheint mir falsch. Ich könnte mir nur erklären, dass es eine Kurzform für "aber ich erzähle es dir sicherheitshalber trotzdem mal:" darstellt (mit Doppelpunkt).

Ist die Verwendung korrekt? Wäre das auch in Schriftsprache erlaubt? Guter/schlechter Stil?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**„Ich weiß nicht …“ ist keine Frage**

*„Ich weiß nicht, ob …“* ist keine Frage, sondern eine Aussage. Das Subjekt steht vor dem Prädikat. *„Weiß ich, ob …?“* wäre eine Frage, die aber ein wenig seltsam daherkommt, weil sie ja an den Fragesteller selbst gerichtet ist. Du schreibst ja sogar selbst, dass der Fragesteller *sich* (also nicht seine Zuhörer) fragt. Sollte er nun darauf warten, dass er von sich selbst eine Antwort erhält? Wohl kaum.

Fragen beginnen mit einem Prädikat, Aussagen beginnen mit einem Subjekt.

Das sind Fragen (Prädikat vor Subjekt):

> Regnet es?
>   Weiß ich, ob hier alle mit der Evolutionstheorie vertraut sind?

Das, was einen Satz zur Frage macht, ist nicht das Fragezeichen am Ende des Satzes. Das Fragezeichen wird nämlich nicht ausgesprochen, es existiert nur in der Schriftform. Fragen erkennt man vielmehr an der Wortstellung.

Das sind Aussagen (Prädikat nach Subjekt):

> Es regnet nicht.
>   Ich weiß nicht, ob hier alle mit der Evolutionstheorie vertraut sind.

Da der Sprecher also gar keine Frage stellt, muss er auch auf keine Antwort warten, sondern kann ohne Unterbrechung weiterreden.

Das letzte Beispiel bringt zum Ausdruck, dass der Sprecher nicht vollständig über den Wissensstand seiner Zuhörer informiert ist. Dieser Satz liefert eine Information über den Sprecher, er liefert jedoch keine Information über die Zuhörer, und dieser Satz ist auch nicht geeignet, um in den Besitz von neuen Informationen zu gelangen. Wollte der Sprecher tatsächlich neues Wissen über seine Zuhörer erlangen, müsste es diese Frage aussprechen:

> Sind hier alle mit der Evolutionstheorie vertraut?

In diesem Fall wäre auch das Warten auf eine Antwort angebracht.

---

**ABER**

Das Wort „aber“ taucht in zwei Varianten auf.

*„aber“ als Konjunktion des Gegensatzes*

> Ich mag keine Gurken, *aber* Gurkensalat esse ich trotzdem gerne.
>   Ich bin noch müde, *aber* ich muss trotzdem aufstehen.

In diesen Beispielen drückt „aber“ einen Gegensatz aus und tritt, ähnlich wie „und“ und „oder“ als Konjunktion, also als Satz-Verbinder auf.

*„aber“ als hervorhebendes und verstärkendes Modalpartikel*

> (Vater beobachtet wie sein Sohn über eine Pizza herfällt): „Na, du hast *aber* einen Hunger!“
>   (Beim ersten Anblick des Eiffelturms): „Der ist *aber* groß!“

Hier wird kein Gegensatz zum Ausdruck gebracht. Das Wort „aber“ soll hier die Aussage dramatischer gestalten und sie verstärken und betonen.

---

***„aber“* als Konjunktion mit hervorhebender Wirkung**

In der Konstruktion „Ich weiß nicht, ob du es weißt, aber …“ tritt das Wort „aber“ als Konjunktion, also als Bindeglied zwischen zwei Teilsätzen, auf. Andererseits bringt es in diesem Fall keinen Gegensatz zum Ausdruck, sondern leitet, gemeinsam mit der Phrase „Ich weiß nicht, ob du es weißt“, die Verkündigung einer mutmaßlichen Neuigkeit ein. Dieses „aber“ hat also eine hervorhebende Wirkung.

Die Konstruktion „Ich weiß nicht, ob …, aber …“ bedeutet eigentlich ja eher „Ich habe die Vermutung, dass nicht …, und daher …“

> Ich weiß nicht, ob schon jemand auf diesem Gipfel war, aber ich will ihn morgen besteigen.
>
> Ich habe die Vermutung, dass noch niemand auf diesem Gipfel war, und daher will ich ihn morgen besteigen.

Umgangssprachlich ist diese Konstruktion durchaus gängig. Auch ein Politiker, der von einer Tribüne zu einer großen Menschenmenge spricht, könnte diese Konstruktion verwenden.

In geschriebenen Texten wird die zweite Person ja ohnehin selten verwendet (der Schreiber wendet sich selten direkt an den Leser), daher wird man diese Konstruktion auch selten in geschriebenen Texten finden. Doch selbst wenn man sich direkt an den Leser wendet, ist es meist keine gute Idee, in geschriebener Form Mutmaßungen über den Wissensstand des Lesers anzudeuten.

Comment: Der "und daher" Vermutung schließe ich mich aber nicht an. Stattdessen passt hier eher ein "nichtdestotrotz".

Comment: "Aber" beschreibt nicht immer einen Gegensatz, sondern oft auch eine Einschränkung ("Wir waren in Berlin, aber nur einen Tag" – auch wer nur einen Tag in Berlin war, war in Berlin). Und selbst wenn das "aber" mit einer Verneinung verbunden ist, drückt es *nicht* den Gegensatz, sondern die Gemeinsamkeit oder Ähnlichkeit aus ("Wir waren nicht in Berlin, aber in Potsdam": Die Aussage "wir waren in Berlin" wird zwar verneint, aber die Wahrheit liegt doch nahe dran – im Gegensatz zu "Wir waren nicht in Berlin, sondern in Potsdam": hier wird nicht die Gemeinsamkeit, sondern der Gegensatz betont).

Comment: @celtschk: das sollte eigentlich eine Antwort sein, die einzig richtige nämlich.

Comment: @Takkat: Es wäre keine Antwort auf die originale Frage (es gibt ja keine Gemeinsamkeit des Wissens um eine Sache und deren Erklärung). MUSEN ist es eine "Verkürzung" von: "Ich weiß nicht, ob Du es bereits weißt, *daher könnte meine Information unnötig sein,* aber *ich sage es trotzdem,* ich bin sein einer Woche arbeitslos." Entsprecjhend beim Gipferl-Beispiel: "Ich weiß nicht, ob schon jemand auf dem Gipfel war, *deshalb könnte die Besteigung mir nichts bringen,* aber *ich könnte doch der erste sein, ich will ihn *deshalb* morgen besteigen." (kursiv ist jeweils das, was "fehlt").

Answer (score 2):

Meiner Meinung nach ist der Gebrauch von "aber" in beiden Beispielen, besonders aber in dem ersten, nicht gut, obwohl es stimmt, dass so etwas gelegentlich zu hören ist. Es entsteht sofort der Eindruck, dass der Sprechende oder Schreibende zu faul ist, sich eine leicht zu findende bessere Variante ohne "aber" zu überlegen. In einem geschriebenen Text lässt so etwas den Leser auf jeden Fall stutzen und nötigt ihn, den Satz noch einmal zu lesen.